# SQL. How to combine subquery and join correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery

I need to list the customer name(s) and their project title(s) that has employee `GLC` working on a task but not employee `CAC` working on a task.**

I tried the following, but got an empty set:

```
select 
   c.custname, p.pjtitle
from 
   (select taskno pjno
    from task 
    where taskno not in
                 (select taskno
                  from task
                  where empid = 'CAC')
    and empid = 'GLC') t
join project p on p.pjno = t.pjno
join customer c on p.custno = c.custno;
```

How should I use `join` and `subquery` correctly?

Comment: Are you need CustomerName and ProjectTital that has employee 'GLC' and 'CAC'?

Comment: I need to list the customer name(s) and their project title(s) that has employee `GLC` working on a task but not employee `CAC` working on a task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.custname, p.pjtitle
  FROM customer c
  JOIN project p ON p.custno = c.custno
  JOIN task t ON p.pjno=t.pjno
 WHERE t.empid='GLC'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM task t1 WHERE t.pjno=t1.pjno AND t1.empid='CAC')
;
```

Comment: Sorry, I originally missed the "t1." in the final "t1.empid='CAC'"

Comment: PJNO 6666 does have GLC - taskno 73 and CAC is not on 6666.

Comment: Thank You! I have just rechecked it. The query is correct. I am sorry for my last comment. Would you kindly explain me the logic of the very last line: `AND NOT EXISTS......`...i am a little confused:) thank you

Comment: In tasks, I see that there are only 3 that GLC is on. Of those, CAC is on 2. So the only possible result is 6666... 5555 GLC(11) and CAC(13)
6666 GLC(73)
7777 GLC(12) and CAC(22)

Comment: Sure, the last line has the not exists. - You don't want any PJNO's where there is a join to CAC. So that filters out 5555 and 7777

Comment: yes, i understand this logic... I am confused what does `select null` do? Is it selecting the `null` column?

Comment: For a more detailed explanation - you compare t to t1 (another copy of the tasks table) where the two tables rows have the same PJNO. Then you filter out all PJNOs in t1 where there is a row with empid=CAC.   The SELECT NULL is just to not bother returning anything, you could also say SELECT 1 or SELECT * - but the latter takes more processing.

Comment: Because you're doing an EXISTS or NOT EXISTS, Oracle doesn't do anything with the return, but is just evaluating a boolean condition. That's why we can return anything

Answer (score 2):

If you want the customer name and the project name, then presumably you do not want duplicates.  This is an example of a set-within-sets subquery.  I think the best solution is to use aggregation, because that offers the most flexibility in describing the conditions.

```
SELECT c.custname, p.pjtitle 
FROM customer c join
     project P
     ON P.CUSTNO = P.CUSTNO join
     task t ON t.pjno = p.pjno
group by c.custname, p.pjtitle 
having sum(case when empid = 'GLC' > 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when empid = 'CAC' > 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The two parts to the having clause are counting the number of times that each employee is working on the particular project.  The first says "make sure GLC is working on at least once task" and the second says "make sure CAC is working on no tasks".

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very thoughtful solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need customername and project tital with only GLC employee then used below query

```
SELECT  c.custname ,
        p.pjtitle
FROM    Customer AS c
        INNER JOIN project AS p ON c.CUSTNO = p.CUSTNO
        INNER JOIN task AS t ON p.PJNO = t.PJNO
WHERE   t.EMPID = 'GLC'
```

and if you want with both employee GLC and CAC then

```
SELECT  c.custname ,
        p.pjtitle
FROM    Customer AS c
        INNER JOIN project AS p ON c.CUSTNO = p.CUSTNO
        INNER JOIN task AS t ON p.PJNO = t.PJNO
WHERE   t.EMPID = 'GLC'
        AND t.EMPID = 'CAC'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. BUT I need to list the customer names and their project titles that have employee `GLC` working on a task BUT NOT employee `CAC` working on a task. However, your 1st answer gives employees `GLC`. Second, `GLC` and `CAC`. I need `GLC` BUT NOT `CAC`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.custname, p.pjtitle 
FROM customer AS c 
JOIN project AS P ON P.CUSTNO = P.CUSTNO
JOIN tack AS t ON t.pjno = p.pjno
WHERE t.empid = 'GLC'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM TASK WHERE empid = 'GLC' AND empid = 'CAC');
```

Comment: This is the same answer as above

Comment: @Sobaka~ and also edited, previous ver.: 'SELECT c.custname, p.pjtitle 
FROM customer AS c 
JOIN project AS P ON P.CUSTNO = P.CUSTNO
JOIN tack AS t ON t.pjno = p.pjno
WHERE t.empid = 'GLC'
AND t.descrip NOT IN (SELECT descrip FROM TASK WHERE empid = 'GLC' AND empid = 'CAC');'

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer this should work

```
select c.custname, p.pjtitle 
  from project p, customer c where c.custno = p.custno 
and exists
(select t.pjno from task t where t.empid = 'GLC' and p.pjno = t.pjno 
and   t.pjno not IN (select pjno from task where empid = 'CAC'))
```